# Syncing Apple Calendar in NetCore 2.1

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm creating a calendar app that requires me to link and sync with multiple calendars. I've already implemented Google, and Microsoft. However, i'm having a difficult time looking for documentations on how i'll be able to retrieve and save events from an apple calendar through my web application.

Does anyone have any leads? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hey fam, do you still need help on this?

Comment: Hey Khen! Not for the mean time, but any sample sources would be great.